# Pass function reference with unknown parameter type in Go

Tags: go

I am working with a third-party library with two functions that each return different types. E.g. `ArticleResponse` and `CommentResponse`.

I would like to pass the results of calling either of those functions into my own function. As a second argument to that function I would like to pass a function reference that describes how to print that response to stdout.

```
response := GetArticles()
processResponse(response, printResponse)

func printResponse(response <what_type?>) {
    for i := range response.Articles {
        fmt.Println(response.Articles[i].Title)
    }
}
```

It's not clear to me how to coerce or create generic types so that the printResponse function knows what to expect to be passed in its parameters.

If I haven't provided a good enough description of what I'm trying to do here, please let me know and I will edit/update the question.

Comment: If you're dealing with just two types or even a little bit more you can also do something like this https://play.golang.org/p/cVtlTu61b5

Answer (score 7):

Your only real option in this case is for `processResponse` to accept an `interface{}` and a function that accepts the same, and then for `printResponse` to accept the same empty interface and type-assert it (or use a type switch).  For example:

```
func main() {
    response := GetArticles()
    processResponse(response, printResponse)
}

func processResponse(response interface{}, printResponse func(interface{})) 
{
    // Process
    printResponse(response)
}

func printResponse(response interface{}) {
    switch r = reponse.(type) {
    case ArticleResponse:
        for i := range r.Articles {
            fmt.Println(r.Articles[i].Title)
        }
    case CommentResponse:
        for i := range r.Comments {
            fmt.Println(r.Comments[i].Topic, r.Comments[i].User)   
        }
    }
}
```

However, a more common style would be for your response itself to have a Print method (or similar), and for your process function to accept an interface representing that common method.  For example:

```
type ArticleReponse struct {
    // ...
}

func (a ArticleReponse) Print() {
    for i := range a.Articles {
        fmt.Println(a.Articles[i].Title)
    }
}

type CommentResponse struct {
    // ...
}

func (c CommentResponse) Print() {
    for i := range c.Comments {
        fmt.Println(c.Comments[i].Topic, c.Comment[i].User)
    }
}

type Response interface {
    Print()
}

func main() {
    response := GetArticles()
    processResponse(response)
}

func processResponse(response Response) 
{
    // Process
    response.Print()
}
```

This style allows the response types themselves to define their printing behavior, while the `processResponse` function only knows that it got some type that's capable of printing itself.  This also allows you to add other methods to the Response interface that `processResponse` (or anything else) might need in order to interact with those types, without actually having to know which type it's been given.  This makes your code substantially less brittle, as it's no longer dependent on the actual implementation details of each response type.  It also allows you to unit test `processReponse` in isolation by mocking out the `Response` interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Content` & `ContentList` interfaces

```
type Content interface {
    GetTitle() string    
}

type ContentList interface {
    Contents() []Content 
}


func printResponse(response ContentList) {
    for content := range response.Contents() {
        fmt.Println(content.GetTitle())
    }
}
```

Then `ArticleResponse` & `CommentResponse` should implement the `ContentList` interface and `Aticle` & `Comment` should implement the `Content` interface.